# Extending target-action methods with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

```
class A{

     func addTarget(target: Any, action: Selector)
}
```

Let's say I don't have class A source available (framework). How would I extend this class reactively to emit Rx events through an Observable?

I can create a class that just forwards the events through a PublishSubject, but in that case I wouldn't be creating a Reactive extension but doing it through a proxy class.

```
let a = A()
let del = CustomClassThatAddsItselfAsATarget(a)
del.event.subscribe( ...
```

instead of

```
let a = A()
a.rx.event.subscribe( ...
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the problem is with either approach? I do not understand the context of your question.

Comment: Let's say you create a Reactive extension where Base is the original class. Which object will add itself as a target(addTarget method) to base? Who retains that object? If you create it in the Observable.create closure, it will get deallocated as soon as the Disposable is returned. Should that class retain the observer and push directly onNext events or create a PublishSubject? I can hack something up, but I'm interested if this has already been covered before. The best solution I found so far is the implementation of ControlEvent and ControlTarget which inherits from RxTarget.

Comment: Does your `class A` extend UIControl?

Comment: @DanielT. Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun exploration. I patterned the below off of how UIControl is set up in RxCocoa.

In answer to your followup questions:

> Which object will add itself as a target(addTarget method) to base?

You have to create a class that is designed to do that. I named it `ATarget`.

> Who retains that object?

You make the object conform to `Disposable` and then it will be retained until disposed of.

```
extension Reactive where Base: A {

    var event: Observable<A> {
        return Observable.create { [weak a = self.base] observer in
            guard let a = a else {
                observer.on(.completed)
                return Disposables.create()
            }

            let aTarget = ATarget(a: a, callback: { a in
                observer.on(.next(a))
            })

            return Disposables.create(with: aTarget.dispose)
        }
        .takeUntil(deallocated)
    }
}

class ATarget: NSObject, Disposable {

    typealias Callback = (A) -> Void
    let selector: Selector = #selector(ATarget.eventHandler)
    weak var a: A?
    var callback: Callback?

    init(a: A, callback: @escaping Callback) {
        self.a = a
        self.callback = callback
        super.init()
        a.addTarget(target: self, action: selector)
    }

    @objc func eventHandler() {
        if let callback = self.callback, let a = self.a {
            callback(a)
        }
    }

    func dispose() {
        self.a?.removeTarget(target: self)
        self.callback = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't consider conforming to Disposable, that makes sense. The way I solved it is by making a ref cycle in the ATarget class to A, and then setting it to nil in Disposables.create{ } block, but I knew there must be a better way.

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about is why the `.takeUntil(deallocated)` is there. Take until _what_ is deallocated?

Answer (score 0):

`RxCocoa` and most other `RxSwift`-based frameworks take the following approach -

`public extension Reactive where Base: TheOriginalClass {`

See [CKRecord+Rx](https://github.com/maxvol/RxCloudKit/blob/master/RxCloudKit/CKRecord%2BRx.swift) or [Bundle+Rx](https://github.com/maxvol/RxOnDemandResources/blob/master/RxOnDemandResources/Bundle%2BRx.swift) for an example of implementation.

Things get more complicated if you need to provide a proxy delegate, but this is out of scope of this question.